# How to know that there is any change in the row sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have data like this

```
DeptId    DeptName    DeptHeadId    DeptBudget
----------------------------------------------
1         HR          1             100000
2         HR-1        2             200000
3         HR-2        5             300000
```

Is there anyway to know that on the particular `departmentid` any column's value has been changed? (do not want to use the timestamp)

Thanks

Comment: How about an AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER?

Comment: Do you want to detect changes as they happen? Or know of historic changes (if so, what is the comparison point, and how do we know that?)

Answer (score 1):

Sample table and data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(DeptId int identity(1,1), 
    DeptName varchar(100),DeptHeadId int, DeptBudget int, HasBeenUpdated bit)

INSERT mytable(DeptName,DeptHeadId, DeptBudget)
values('HR',  1,100000),
      ('HR-1',2,200000),
      ('HR-2',5,300000)

go
```

Trigger Syntax, this will not react on changes in the HasBeenUpdated column, if a row is 'changed' to the current value it will not registre as changed eather:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytable_trg1
ON mytable
INSTEAD OF UPDATE 
AS
MERGE mytable t1
USING
INSERTED t2
ON t1.DeptId = t2.DeptId
WHEN matched THEN
UPDATE 
SET DeptName = t2.DeptName,
    DeptHeadId=t2.DeptHeadId, 
    DeptBudget=t2.DeptBudget, HasBeenUpdated = 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS
      (SELECT t1.DeptName, t1.DeptHeadId, t1.DeptBudget
       EXCEPT 
       SELECT t2.DeptName, t2.DeptHeadId, t2.DeptBudget) 
       THEN 1 ELSE t2.HasBeenUpdated 
    END
;

go
```

Testing trigger:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET DeptName = 'HR-0' 
WHERE deptid = 1
```

Result

```
SELECT * FROM mytable

DeptId DeptName    DeptHeadId    DeptBudget  HasBeenUpdated
1      HR-0        1             100000      1
2      HR-1        2             200000      NULL
3      HR-2        5             300000      NULL
```

To reset before next update check

```
UPDATE mytable
SET HasBeenUpdated = 0 
WHERE HasBeenUpdated = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 and above supports change tracking. I've not used it myself but I believe it does what you want without using timestamp fields. See [TechNet here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AFTER UPDATE trigger and specify the columns with IF UPDATE, like this:

```
    ....
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN

    IF ( UPDATE (DeptName) OR UPDATE (DeptBudget) )
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add one column with datatype (Bit) for updated row or not.

make a trigger on your table like below.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trigforisupdateornot
   ON  dbo.triggertable
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
if (UPDATE(DeptName) OR
    UPDATE(DeptHeadId) OR   
    UPDATE(DeptBudget))
Begin
    Update triggertable
    Set IsUpdate = 1
    Where Deptid = (Select deptid From inserted)
End
END
GO
```

execute this query before update

```
Select *
From triggertable
```

the output of above query.

```
DeptId      DeptName       DeptHeadId  DeptBudget  IsUpdate
----------- ----------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- --------
1           HR                1           100000      NULL
2           HR-1              2           200000      NULL
3           HR-2              5           300000      NULL
```

now execute below query to update record.

```
Update triggertable
Set deptname = deptname
where deptid = 1
```

now the output will be

```
DeptId      DeptName       DeptHeadId  DeptBudget  IsUpdate
----------- ----------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- --------
1           HR                1           100000      1
2           HR-1              2           200000      NULL
3           HR-2              5           300000      NULL
```

where IsUpdate = 1 is updated row.

Answer (score 0):

You could store Checksum(DeptName,    DeptHeadId,    DeptBudget) in the table, then compare it with current Checksum value to see if it matches. If it doesnt match, you know it has changed, then make the action and update checksum column.